# How to delete row in Sqlite with ContextMenu?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-listfragment

I want to delete row in Sqlite database. Opening pop up when pressed long on Listview.(Popup opens with ContextMenu). Pop up is include two options:"Delete","Update". When pressed "Delete" I want to delete that row.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Action");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Update");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ListView lst=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewVeriler);

    if(item.getTitle()=="Delete"){function1(item.getItemId());}
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Update"){function2(item.getItemId());}
    else {return false;}
    return true;
}

public void function1(int id){
    ListView lst=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewVeriler);
    VeriTabani vt=new VeriTabani(MainActivity.this); 
   //VeriTabani is my database class
    int idd=(int)lst.getSelectedItemId();
    vt.VeriSil(idd);
  //VeriSil is delete method in VeriTabanı class
    Toast.makeText(this, "Deleted Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void function2(int id){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Update Person", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   // I will open UpdateAction here
}


public void VeriSil(int id){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    try {
                   db.delete(TABLO_KISILER, ROW_ID_ + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    }
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this method in your **ContentProvider**

```
public static void deleteRow(int id)
{
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+YOUR_TABLE_NAME+" WHERE id= ?",new Object[]{id});
}
```

in you activity call the method

```
mContentProvider.deleteRow(id)
```

extra information

```
public void function1(int id){
    ListView lst=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewVeriler);
    VeriTabani vt=new VeriTabani(MainActivity.this); 
   //VeriTabani is my database class
    int idd=(int)lst.getSelectedItemId();
    mContentProvider.deleteRow(idd);
  //VeriSil is delete method in VeriTabanı class
    Toast.makeText(this, "Deleted Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

all done

good luck !